# Google bar Chart filling with blank space where no data is available

Tags: mysql, charts

I try to make some charts with Google Chart and mysql as data source.

I want to create a chart with 24 columns for each hour one. I want that all hours are showing up, even them with no data availabile for the future hours of a day.

**I get something like this:**

[image]

**Instead of that what I want:**

[image]

I Think its something that can be done with the MySQL query or maybe with the Google Chart Ticks?

MySQL query:

```
SELECT id
     , year(time) as yr
     , month(time) as mth
     , day(time) as dy
     , hour(time) as hr
     , max(blocks)-min(blocks) as blocks_per_hour
     , DATE_FORMAT(time, '%D %b, %H:%i') as form 
  FROM blockchain 
 WHERE DATE(`time`) = CURDATE() 
 group 
    by year(time)
     , month(time)
     , day(time)
     , hour(time)
```

[SQL Fiddle.com Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86fc55/1/0)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you, I'm just learning. I think you asked for something like this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86fc55/1/0